# @InboundChannelAdapter in Spring-integration is not running continously?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

i am working in spring cloud data flow,there i am having a scenario like reading from the database and send the data to the kafka topic using the @InboundChannelAdapter

Below is the strategy i followed.

->Created common list to store the objects if the list was empty

->if the list have the data i won't poll

->i am sending the values to kafka one by one by using index and after that i will remove the index

if i keep the @Bean it is inserting only the first object in the list to kafka topic.

> {"id":101443442,"name":"Mobile1","price":8000}

if i remove the @Bean then it will insert all empty data into kafka.

> {}

```
public static List<Product> products;

@Bean
public void initList() {
    products = new ArrayList<>();
}    

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = TbeSource.PR1)
public MessageSource<Product> addProducts() {

    if (products.size() == 0) {
        products.add(new Product(101443442, "Mobile1", 8000));
        products.add(new Product(102235434, "book111", 6000));
    }
    MessageBuilder<Product> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(products.get(0));
    products.remove(0);
    return message::build;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

i need to send the data frequently by reading from db ?

Answer (score 0):

Really not clear what you are asking.

If you talk about JDBC then you may consider to use a `JDBC Source` from tout-of-the-box applications for Data Flow.

If you are doing logic yourself to take data from data base, you may consider to use a `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` from Spring Integration for the same `@InboundChannelAdapter` reason.

The rest of your logic with that list is not clear. It is strange to see a `@Bean` on a `void` method. If you need to initialize that `products` and get access from the `MessageSource` implementation, you just need to do `private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();`. Having property as `public` is really a bad practice.